# Filter options on ExtJS ComboBox with typeAhead

Tags: extjs, combobox, typeahead

I basically want to make a combo box look like a textBox with autocomplete/typeahead capabilities.

I have achieved almost everything but filtering the results on type ahead using the following code:

```
var tboxReportaNombre = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    margin: '5 0 0 10',
    store: reportersNamesStore,
    displayField: 'vcReportaNombre',
    valueField: 'vcReportaNombre',
    hideTrigger: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    typeAheadDelay: 100,
    minChars: 2,
    mode: 'local'
});
```

And this is the store I am using:

```
var reportersNamesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['vcReportaNombre'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/SIMAC/Incidencia/GetReportersNames',
    }
});
```

It is working just fine, but when I start typing, I would like the dropdown list to be filtered to match my query. Right now it doesn't (as shown in the image below).

[image: Dropdown not matching my query]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide reportersNamesStore details or a sencha fiddle will be much more useful.

Comment: Thanks @Chetan, I've just added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just solved it, I had to add the properties queryMode set to local and lastQuery set to empty string.

Ending up having this code:

```
var tboxReportaNombre = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    margin: '5 0 0 10',
    store: reportersNamesStore,
    displayField: 'vcReportaNombre',
    valueField: 'vcReportaNombre',
    hideTrigger: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    typeAheadDelay: 100,
    minChars: 2,
    queryMode: 'local',
    lastQuery: ''
});
```

I think Sencha should implement a Typeahead property and methods to its textboxfield.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the same problem but my queryMode is not local.  lastQuery = '' alone doesn't seem to help.  I don't get why queryMode would have affected it.